# С# Как без костылей последовательно перебрать несколько List<string>

Tags: c#, list, foreach

Ребят подскажите как на C# без кучи циклов перебрать несколько List'ов? К примеру есть 3 массива.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() {"1","2","3"};
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() {"4","5"};
List<string> list3 = new List<string>() {"6",};``
```

Как за один цикл перебрать их по очереди ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если по-простому, то:

```
foreach (var item in list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3))
{
    ...
}
```

Если надо соединять произвольное количество списков, можно написать универсальную функцию:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatAll<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> root,
    params IEnumerable<T>[] streams)
{
    IEnumerable<T> result = root;
    foreach (var stream in streams)
    {
        result = result.Concat(stream);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Использование:

```
foreach (var item in list1.ConcatAll(list2, list3))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

С помощью Linq это делается так:

```
foreach (var item in new [] { list1, list2, list3 }.SelectMany(list => list))
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать в двух циклах, как, например

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>() {"1","2","3"};
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>() {"4","5"};
        List<string> list3 = new List<string>() {"6",};

        foreach ( List<string> list in new List<string>[] { list1, list2, list3 } )
        {
            foreach ( string s in list ) Console.Write( s );
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
123456
```