# Как задать списку значения из другой коллекции при инициализации?

Tags: c#, массивы, list, инициализация

```
int[] Nums {get; set;}
List <int> expansion = new List<int>();

public void AddVal(int val)
{
  expansion.Add(val);
  List <int> numsExpanded = new List<int>();
  numsExpanded.AddRange(Nums);
  numsExpanded.AddRange(expansion);                
}
```

Метод `AddVal` создаёт список `numsExpanded`, который должен включать в себя значения из свойства `Nums` и списка `expansion`. Как присвоить списку значения при его инициализации?

Comment: `new List<int>(...);`, где `...` - нужный список. Но учтите, это копирование ссылок, а не объектов, измените в одном, изменится и в другом. Если такое поведение не устраивает, то делайте копию любым удобным методом ([например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1034673/220553)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а если я хочу чтобы мой список при инициализации включал в себя две коллекции, это возможно сделать?

Comment: Тогда [что-то такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576095/220553) делайте.

Comment: А чем AddRange то не устроил? В чём смысл того что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @aepot я не нашёл этого в документации, поэтому спрашиваю, можно ли так сделать.

Comment: Согласно документации в конструктор списка мижно передать только одну коллекцию. Другими словами, документация не врёт. Неизвестно, как вам помочь, если вы либо не обозначаете реальную проблему, либо её просто нет.